# Up to date Spring boot version in submodule & different Spring version in parent

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create the Spring Boot application which is submodule of our project's parent pom (which depends on our internal framework which locks down spring dependency versions - as of now we are at 4.2.4-RELEASE)

If I specify the latest Spring Boot version (1.4.1-RELEASE) which depends on spring 4.3.3-RELEASE, I am facing conflicts

One of them is following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
```

This class was introduced in 4.3, which explains that error

Is there a way how to keep my Spring Boot dependencies up-to-date without updating Spring versions in internal framework?

Comment: I am under the impression it is somehow stupid question, but I thought somebody will give me guidance :)

Comment: I suggest you start debugging (e.g. with `mvn dependency:tree`) and find out what you did wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I used dependency:tree, & found spring's versions of Boot's transitive dependencies were omitted because of duplicates coming from internal framework. I'm not sure though whether I can override version of transitive dependencies of Spring boot itself.

Comment: If I override versions (if possible), this would possibly break functionalities of internal framework. My impression is the only thing I can do is to ask for the upgrade of spring versions or downgrade Spring Boot version

Comment: It's only a little stupid, because one of the goals of Boot is to manage your dependencies - not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to keep all your Spring dependencies in sync by making `spring-boot-starter-parent` your parent.

That sets up all the `<dependencyManagement>` for you, and you should not then be using `<version>` when you pull in specific dependencies.

If you need to override a version managed by the parent, there should be a property that you can change, named e.g. `logback.version`, `spring-security.version`, etc.

You can also stop one of your dependencies from overriding the versions of its dependencies by using `<excludes>` to remove the transitive dependency entirely, and ensuring you pull it in from elsewhere. This is a much more brittle though.

You could also try importing `spring-boot-dependencies` into your `dependencyManagement`, but you're probably making more work for yourself trying to add your existing projects as the Boot project's parent, rather than as dependencies.